# \thanks won't appear in IEEEtran

Tags: titles, ieeetran

I'm writing a article for a conference and using the `IEEEtran` class, this the first paper I'm doing with LaTeX but there's a problem I just can't solve I'm trying to write some acknowledgments but what I write in `\thanks` doesn't seem to appear.

From what I read on the note there doesn't seem to be a package I need to import and the auto completion recognizes `\thanks` but it won't show up in the pdf.

This is how I'm using it:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{My Title}
\author{M.E. Author\thanks{First thanks explaining were I work} C.O. Author\thanks{Second thanks}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

I've checked the console outputs but I don't see any new warning or some such so if anybody has a idea what to do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The class issues a message:

```
** WARNING: \thanks is locked out when in conference mode (line 12).
```

The documentation says, about conference mode,

> The following commands are intentionally disabled: `\thanks`, `\IEEEPARstart`, `\IEEEbiography`, `\IEEEbiographynophoto`, `\IEEEpubid`, `\IEEEpubidadjcol`, `\IEEEmembership`, and `\IEEEaftertitletext`. If needed, they can be reenabled by issuing the command: `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts`.

So issuing `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` before `\begin{document}` will make the acknowledgments appear.

I'd leave that to the conference editors.

Comment: I will try this, but why did they fell the need to disable them?

Comment: @GeorgeBora Ask IEEE. Probably they don't want thanks in "conference mode". In any case it will be just a matter of commenting a line, so there should be no problem.

Comment: I overrided them as you said and now they appear with no additional problems, thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeBora `IEEETran` is generally not used for conferences anymore but you need to find `ieeeconf.cls` online which is easy to access. I don't have a clue about why but even some conferences modify their copies of `ieeeconf.cls` and supply it to the authors. You might recognize this in the proceedings of the past conferences.

Comment: @GeorgeBora Even worse the copy in CTAN database is outdated. I use generally the one [at this link](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/files/ieeeconf.cls). Just save as in lowercase letters into your local folder. Weirdly the copy is dated as 2002. Let me know if you need a working minimal `.tex` file.