# IEEEtran's \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts clashes with \maketitle

Tags: errors, titles, ieeetran

The heading of question says it all.

```
   \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts      
%% INFOCOM 2013 addition:

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
\def\@oddhead{\mbox{}\scriptsize\rightmark \hfil \thepage}%
\def\@evenhead{\scriptsize\thepage \hfil \leftmark\mbox{}}%
\def\@oddfoot{}%
\def\@evenfoot{}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,graphicx,charter, latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
%\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}
% *** SPECIALIZED LIST PACKAGES ***
%


\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
\usepackage{bbm}

% *** ALIGNMENT PACKAGES ***
%

\begin{document}
\title{\bf{XXX}}
\author{XXX
\thanks{This material is based upon work partially supported by XXX}
   \\Department of XXXX
   \\Email: \{XXX\}@XXX.edu
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I am using the `IEEEtran` class for a conference paper. In order to write acknowledgements, I use `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts`. Unfortunately, LaTeX compilation returns many errors, such as "misaligned tab or misplaced `\maketitle`". What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53548/21891) may be of interest.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Also, please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If I make your code compilable by appending `\end{document}` to it, I get no error, only a warning from the `caption` package, which is loaded by `subfig`.

Comment: @jubobs ....my problem is bit subtle.....I do get an overall compiled file....but with errors unrelated to this \thanks....i mean many bad boxes etc which werent showing up earlier now show up...i mean after i use the override lockuts

Comment: @jubobs . i do get "Misplaced alignment tab character & \maketitle"

Comment: also while using texstudio earlier i was getting the compiled file as directly displayed, which I am not getting now since I guess tehre are too many badnesses introduced.

Comment: I too get no error; ensure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using TeXstudio 2.5.2 (SVN 3949M)
Using Qt Version 4.8.4, compiled with Qt 4.8.4 R on a mac.

Comment: TeXstudio is your LaTeX IDE: that's where you type (and perhaps compile) your TeX input. What egreg is referring to is your TeX distribution, which is distinct from your IDE: the TeX distribution contains all the files needed to compile (La)TeX code. The one you use is probably called TeXlive. Make sure it's up to date.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to outdated software